# How to make the Mailing state/province field in Leads as a picklist of states?

Tags: community

How to make the State/Province field in the Leads as a picklist field with state abbreviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn on "State and Country Picklists" in your orgs

[This](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm) document and [this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf) one will help you do it. Below you can find a few excerpts from the articles

> 1. Configure the state and country values you want to use in your
>      organization.
>
> This step is strongly recommended because it gives you the opportunity
>   to customize state and country values. It ensures that state and
>   country data continues to work with the third-party systems you have
>   integrated with Salesforce.
>
> 2. Scan your organization’s data and customizations to see how they’ll
>      be affected by the switch.
>
> Convert data and update customizations, such as list views, reports,
>   and workflow rules, so that they continue to work with the new field
>   type.
>
> 3. Convert existing data.
>
> The conversion process lets you map the various values in your
>   organization to standard picklist values. For example, you might want
>   to map U.S., USA, and United States to US.
>
> 4. Turn on the picklists for your users.
>
> If you turn on state and country picklists without configuring values,
>   scanning your organization, and converting existing data, users can
>   use the picklists in new records. However, all existing data is
>   incompatible with the new format, which could compromise data
>   consistency and integrity across the two field formats.
>
> 5. Optionally, rescan and fix customizations or records that have been created or edited since your first scan.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new feature in Salesforce. To enable State and Country Picklists go to Setup->Data Management->State and Country Picklists and follow the prompts. This happens Org.-wide so it's not just in Leads.